# Do all external hard drives require a power supply with positive polarity?

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply

I am shopping for an AC/DC power adapter for an external hard drive, and I've noticed that the power supply required for the couple of the external hard drives I looked at is always with positive polarity. This made me wonder: Do all external hard drives require a power supply with positive polarity? In other words, if I buy AC/DC power adapter for an external hard drive, should its output always have positive polarity, or does that depend on the external hard drive?

Comment: There is one 'self evident' answer to your question: Yes. Now whether to extend on that depends on what you're actually asking; it is somewhat fuzzy. I have yet to something differing from that, and I have been tinkering with computer hardware and other electronics for decades. (Not old UK -made cars though... ;-)

Comment: @Hannu thanks, to rephrase: if I buy AC/DC power adapter for an external hard drive, should its output always have positive polarity, or does that depend on the external hard drive?

Comment: If you find such a thing (that is directly connectable) it should be correctly wired. Now I'd recommend look for a USB caddy instead. => https://www.google.com/search?q=USB+HDD+caddy

Comment: All electronics requires some kind of power source where one conductor is at a higher polarity than the other. A -12V supply can simply be considered as one where the more positive connection has been labelled as "0V" and the distinction of "positive" and "negative" supplies only becomes important where multiple supplies are used together with a common 0V or ground connection. Taken individually every power supply has an inherent positive terminal alongside a negative one. You probably need to clarify exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you asking about why power is on a particular pin? I.e. connector polarity. Or are you asking why it is a +12V supply rather than a -12V supply? As it stands your question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for the feedback, I am asking if when I buys an AC/DC power adapter for an external hard drive, should the output of the adapter always have positive polarity, or does that depend on the external hard drive?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt every electrical device in existence has a positive polarity **and** a negative polarity. Even if the device has a -12V supply, by definition the 0V is "more positive" than the -12V, and for all intents and purposes for single voltage supplies the nomenclature is vaguely irrelevant and a -12V supply can be seen as +12V if you measure with the -12 as "ground". It is the potential difference that matters. Again, are you asking about electrical polarity as in +12 or -12V or connector polarity, as in which pin is considered positive?

Answer (score 3):

Its more that negative center barrel plugs are *less* common and tend to be found (very rarely) in guitar pedals. Most barrel plugs are center *negative* and PSUs tend to follow that.

For safety's sake though it is always good to double check.